A word or phrase that means "picky about something they can't have"
I'm searching for a word, phrase, or even an idiom to describe someone who is very picky about things out of their reach. For example, they may love Lamborghinis but think Ferraris are too overstyled or aggressive, but not be in a position to ever own one. They may find a particular super model attractive but find another to be below their standards, but not be in a position to ever date one.
I found fastidious, which describes the overly picky aspect, but doesn't address that the person is picky about something that cannot possibly impact their life. If it were simply about cars, the phrase "too fast too stidious" would be amazing, but I want to describe the person more than the desire because the behavior often transcends a particular preference group.
The best word/phrase would be somewhat insulting and less of a passive diagnosis.
I would use the word/phrase like this:
"Mike can be a chore to talk to. He has strong opinions and is also ___________. My parents just bought a vacation house on a lake and when I showed him pictures he said he wouldn't buy that vacation house because it faces East and not West, which is ridiculous because he can't even afford the rent on his tiny apartment."

stidious Is that even a word?

@user405662 It is not a word. The word is fastidious, but the phrase plays on the popular Fast and Furious movie franchise, whose sequel was titled "Too Fast Too Furious"

Although not an exact match, "choosy beggar" describes someone who is picky in a situation where they can't really afford to be.

I think the spirit of the phrase is there, but it doesn't capture that these things he's choosy about aren't even being offered.

Again, not the match you are looking for but another word is "academic" meaning a choice is only of theoretical interest because it is practically impossible e.g. "Which diamond ring you like more is purely academic, because I can’t afford either one."

That one is definitely a good fit for a proper discussion or debate on the merits of things beyond reach.

Beggars can't be choosers.

That commonly implies that something is on offer but is rejected because an alternative is preferred. But the question is for being picky about unattainable things.

The phrase "finicky window shopper" may capture the combination of being quick to find fault with items on offer and yet not being in a position to buy those items if they did meet one's standards.

The classic sour grapes fits the bill.

disparagement of something that has proven unattainable

His criticisms are just sour grapes.
[Merriam-Webster]
So you could say Mikes's criticisms/nitpicks are sour grapes.

I would like sour grapes here, but what it lacks is that all of the grapes are unattainable and this person only says some are sour, but prefers another sort of unattainable grape.

I'm thinking more on this answer, it's really just incomplete and needs another word. I almost want to call him a sour grape connoisseur. It really contains the pretension and the unattainability. I could even say "He's worse than a sour grape connoisseur. He's trying to make wine out of his own sour grapes. He's a sour grape sommelier."

In the source of this phrase, the grapes are called sour because they can't be reached. It's a way to cope with not getting something by saying it's probably bad anyway. Also, sommeliers don't make wine.
